# Is it possible to test my Parse.com setup after making app changes if the app is already in the app store?

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform

I've setup my app with Parse.com and for the first release and everything was working.  Since, I've updated the app and changed my Parse.com integration slightly.

I've got my single production certificate setup in Parse for notifications.

Before submitting these updates to the App Store, is it possible to test these new features without interrupting or sending test notifications out to current users?

Comment: Are current users setup for push notifications?

Comment: Current users are able to use push notifications, however I'd like to validate the changes made prior to pushing a new version to the app store.

Comment: So they can push notifications...but did you register them for remote notifications in your AppDelegate in the current production code?

Comment: Yes, that had been done and push notifications had been working prior to the first submission in my testing.  My question is -- can I send out test notifications that won't go out to all subscribers of the notifications. I've added `[PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];` to get better app tracking, and would like to try to validate this change and that nothing has changed with the ability to receive notifications.  I don't see the ability to segment my group of iOS users who have approved notifications.

Comment: have you tried sending targets push notifications from the parse dashboard?

Comment: You could try setting the channel of your push notification to "TestChannel" or something within the testing version of your app, then create a new push notification that only broadcasts to installations subscribed to "TestChannel" instead of all users

Comment: @sfeuerstein please respond with that answer I just discovered that solution tinkering with the dashboard.  That was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the channel of your push notification to "TestChannel" or something within the testing version of your app, then create a new push notification that only broadcasts to installations subscribed to "TestChannel" instead of all users

Comment: This worked for me by going to push notification to segment --> iOS Devices --> Installation must match appName isEqual to 'uniqueAppTestName'